# Adding Characters between other characters in C++

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I have a string `12345` and another string `abcde`. How would I go about making the string `1a2b3c4d5e`.

Comment: LOL Would you recommend using the insert function? I tried using it but I did it wrong.

Comment: suggest you post your code attempt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string foo1 = "12345";
string foo2 = "abcde";
string out;
int a;

for (a = 0;a < 5;a++)
{
    out += foo1[a];
    out += foo2[a];
}
```

The answer is in `out`.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to add the two ASCII codes together.

Comment: do out += foo1[a];  out+=foo2[a];

Comment: Oh, it works my compiler, but just to make it clear, I have edited my answer with Keith's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

since this seems like homework,  the general strategy is :-

take a character from 1 string, add it to a new one, take a character from the other string, also add it to the new one,  repeat for all the letters in each string.

you will have to make sure you can deal with strings of different lengths.